# Change name for all checkbox

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on my project and I need to change the name of all my checkbox to sql datas.

```
string SelectFile = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Irish\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Animalsssssss.accdb";
        string SelectCode = "Select SAMPLE from Animals";
        OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(SelectFile);
        OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand(SelectCode, con2);
        con2.Open();
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        reader = com2.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string[] arrays = new string[] {reader["BASICEDSeminar"].ToString()};
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
            {
                CheckBox[] cbo = new CheckBox[]{checkBox0,checkBox1,checkBox2};
                cbo[i].Text = arrays[i];
                
            }
        }
        con2.Close();
```

Output should be:

Before Execution

> checkBox0's name is still the same.
>
> checkBox1's name is still the same.
>
> checkBox2's name is still the same.

After Execution

> checkBox0's will change to Apple.
>
> checkBox0's will change to Banana.
>
> checkBox0's will change to Dog.

Comment: Not sure, whether you want to change control name or text. What issue are you getting in above code?

Comment: What does `reader["BASICEDSeminar"]` return?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my suggestion. Hope to help my friend!

```
var arrays = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var lstCheckbox = new List<CheckBox>();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var checkbox = new CheckBox
    {
        Text = arrays[i],
        ID = "chk" + i
    };
    lstCheckbox.Add(checkbox);
 }
```